# Connection of MariaDB 11.2 to work with Mathematica 13.3.1

Tags: java, databaselink, databases, jdbc

I would like to get the proper driver settings in place to permit the
mariaDB database to connect to Mathematica via a JDBC driver running on
a Windows11 64-bit machine.

I've got mariaDB version 11.2 installed at the user level in the following directory: "C:\Program Files\MariaDB 11.2" and it runs using port 3306 using user="root" password="mypassword".  I do not have any existing mariaDB databases I can connect to yet and am unsure if one needs to be created *apriori* for a connection between the two applications to be established or where it or suitable configuration files may need to be placed. I am presuming the test database file that is generated upon installation suffices.

Although I have had experience using MS Access with MMA and limited experience with MySQL, I thought mariaDB might be worth exploring since I am interested in WikiData and understand that mariaDB is the underlying engine.  Further, I understand it both runs faster and has a more flexible/open license than does MySQL.

I've tried a variety of approaches to establish a connection, including the Connection wizard and the JDBCConnector MySQL(Connector/J), but am unsure what responses to provide the wizard for Hostname or Name.  When I attempt to test the connection I get a JDBC error.  Likewise,various  attempts to establish an SQLConnection using DatabaseLink` directly have also failed.

**Does anyone have an approach (working configuration files and their locations) that work to establish a connection between mariaDB Vers. 11.2 and Mathematica Vers. 13.3.1?**

Answer (score 1):

After getting some additional information from WRI regarding alternative connections for various databases not in their examples, I was able to make the connection once I had properly set the proper classpath to the driver (one of two for MariaDB), utilizing the default port of 3306 used by MariaDB and a previously created database "scorpaenoid", which was installed at the system level.  Using the previously established name for my machine "stonefish" the following worked:

```
 conn = OpenSQLConnection[
   JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", 
   "stonefish:3306/scorpaenoid"], 
   "Username" -> "root", "Password" -> "secret 
   password"]
```

All that remains now is to create a non-root user and provide suitable privileges to work with it.

Hopefully, this will save some time for others who, like me, initially find the online documentation a bit confusing. Of course, the settings will be different if the database and drivers are not set up on a local host but in the cloud.